# How to import something that exists in js but not in typescript types and remove errors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm using [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) and in this library, they [export](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/blob/master/index.js):

```
export {
  listenToKeyboardEvents,
  KeyboardAwareFlatList,
  KeyboardAwareSectionList,
  KeyboardAwareScrollView
}
```

But in their [`index.d.ts`](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/blob/master/index.d.ts) there's no type for `listenToKeyboardEvents`

So when I import `listenToKeyboardEvents` it works but I keep getting the ts error:

> Module '"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view"' has no exported member 'listenToKeyboardEvents'.

What workarounds I can make to fix this error while the library don't update the types?

Comment: Did you try to `@ts-ignore` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

```typescript
declare module "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view" {
  export const listenToKeyboardEvents: any // provide actual type
}
```